KQL Query: Users that have never signed in
Firstly, my KQl is newbie level.
So I have been using the following query to pull users not logged in 90+ days but how do I get the list of users that have no last login date?
   SigninLogs
   | extend d = parse_json(AuthenticationDetails)
   | extend LoginTimestamp = todatetime(d[0].authenticationStepDateTime)
   | where OperationName == "Sign-in activity"
   | summarize max(LoginTimestamp) by Identity
   | where max_LoginTimestamp < ago(90d)
   | distinct Identity

I tried altering it to "> ago(0d)", but i get no results.

Try to use an outer join or left anti join to compare a list of all users against those who have login records.

Follow the below steps to use outer join or left anti join where left anti join returns only records from the left table that do not have a match in the right table as you can see in the below example code.
left anti join:
let TableA = datatable(User:string, Role:string)
[
    "Pavan", "Admin",
    "Sai", "User",
    "Balaji", "Admin",
    "Arif", "User"
];

let TableB = datatable(User:string, LoginTimestamp:datetime)
[
    "Pavan", datetime(2023-12-01 09:00:00),
    "Sai", datetime(2023-12-02 14:00:00)
];

TableA
| join kind=leftanti (TableB) on User

Output:

Outer Join:
Outer Join returns all records from both tables. If there is no match, the fields from the other table will be null as you can see in the below example.
TableA
| join kind=fullouter (TableB) on User

Output:

